# Excel calculate cells only if all have value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have Cells A, B and C. Cell C = B - A. The problem is if cell B does not have a value, Cell C has a value of (A). I would like cell C to not have a value if cell B does not have a value.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative to this would be to use `ISBLANK()` inside the `IF` statement in cell `C?`.

`IF(ISBLANK(B1), "", B1-A1)`

This checks to see if `B1` is blank. If true, it returns nothing. Otherwise it will run the calculation.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using an if statement

Here is the formula for if B is empty, A may or may not be empty.

```
=IF(B1="","",B1-A1)
```

Here is the formula for if A or B is empty.

```
=IF(OR(B1="",A1=""),"",B1-A1)
```

The formula would replace the contents of cell C

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer counting the number of non-empty cells.

```
=IF(COUNTA(A1:B1)=2,B1-A1,"")
```